# ASP.Net C# helper, return an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-2

Simple question: I need to return an array from a helper function:

```
@helper arrayBuilder(){
      string pages = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["siteNav"];
      pages = pages.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
      string[] pagesTable = pages.Split(',');

   return pagesTable;
}
```

Why on earth isnt this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This method shouldn't be a helper function. This should be in your controller and returned in your model. Helper functions are there for display only. A clue to this is because you are calling `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I suspected i was adding code in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using [@function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2010/07/30/using-functions-in-an-asp-net-page-with-razor-syntax.aspx) syntax would help here?

[@helper](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/173/The-Difference-Between-@Helpers-and-@Functions-In-WebMatrix) returns an item to render, e.g. some HTML, but I think that @function should allow you return a value